# Detecting on my webpage if my app is installed or not (Android)

Tags: android, redirect

I'm trying to figure out a solution to my use case. Every page I've read tells me that this is not possible yet I see websites (such as imgur) do this.

I work for an e-commerce website. Our use case is the following:

- When a user comes to our website, (either by typing in the URL or through a 3rd party click), we want anyone who has our app to be redirected straight to the app (deep linked).
- If the user does not have an app, we want the customer to continue browsing our mobile site. We provide the user with the ability to download our app (if they wish to) by messaging this on the mobile site but we do not want to automatically send them to the app store without their consent.

So far, we have been able to figure out how to deal with the situation of a customer going directly to the app or the app store. However, we cannot figure out how to send a user with the app to the app and a user without the app to our mobile web experience.

This is specifically for Android users as we have solved this problem in iOS.

Reason for the request:
Like most ecommerce sites, we receives visitors from 3rd party links (social or marketing). Our users who have the app prefer landing on the app. However, our users who do not have the app dislike being redirected to the app store as it sends the message that they cannot get to our offerings until the app is installed which is a horrible customer experience. This is the reason for the request.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, but I think this should work:

1)In your app, have an activity that has an intent filter

```
  <data android:scheme="http"
      android:host="www.example.com"
      android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
```

This will deep link to your app when an http request is made to that address
2)If the user gets to your website, that means he didn't have the app.  Display as normal.
3)Check the OS when a request comes on the server.  If its android, add in a link to the play store.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if that will strip out any variables from the original URL?